# Looping through Variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, loops

I have a row vector 'A' (length 3) of the following form:

```
A= x+y, y+4x^2, x+z
```

I want to create the variables `F(1)` `F(2)` and `F(3)` from my `A` vector in Matlab.

The end result should look something like this.

```
F(1) = x+y

F(2) = y+4x2

F(3) = x+z
```

I tried with cell arrays and various sorts of loops but can not find the right solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it a symbolic array?

Comment: You'll need to clarify some things in order for anyone to be able to answer. Are `x` `y` and `z` symbolic variables? When you say `F(1)`, what do you mean as for the class of `F`?

Comment: `syms('x','y','z'); A = [x+y,y+4*x^2,x+z]; A(1)` seems to do the job, I don't understand

Comment: It's just a typo then, you wrote `F` instead of `A` in your question which is a bit confusing